# Can we use a single Service Provider or Relying Party to authenticate multiple web apps

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs, service-provider

The design problem which i am facing is that, we are having multiple web applications like webapp1,webapp2, webapp3 and don't want to create a dedicated service provider which uses a dedicated relying party to authenticate dedicated application rather than want to create a common Service Provider(which is created as a Relying Party within ADFS) to which all different web applications will be reaching out to get the users authenticated and in return get the claims/token.
By having such kind of a design, i will get rid of creating a multiple SP(or Relying Party) for each web application, saying that there will be a single source of web api for authentication.

But doing this way i am not sure whether is it a right approach or not, so far what i came to know is that Single Application talks to it's dedicated Service Provider which talks to a dedicated Relying Party.
I am using SAML as an authentication language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

•   You cannot create a common(single) relying party trust for multiple SaaS applications as every SaaS application/platform that is to be federated with ADFS for providing single sign-on authentication to that SaaS platform using Active Directory attributes is a different from each other in the sense that every SaaS app has a different(unique) domain name, a different(unique) public IP address assigned by IANA in public and global DNS registries.

•   Thus, since every SaaS app/platform is unique, their federation metadata URLs containing the federation configuration information are different and unique as every SaaS app is hosted and built for a different purpose on a business specific and required platform build. Therefore, the relying party trust formed between the on premises Active directory and the Service provider, i.e., SaaS app through ADFS is a one-to-one trust connection between the platforms to let the identities authorized by the Active Directory be able to login to the SaaS platform.

•   Also, the claims that will be generated against the attributes requested from Active directory for authentication purposes will be unique and different for each SaaS app according to the relying party trust created and the encryption protocol used for that purpose.

Please find the below documentation links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/adfs

Comment: so that means, it won't be a correct design approach and hence one to one relationship has to be between Relying party and web application as a best practice...by the way thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes, correct, that's the way it should be!